# CSS gradient impossible to refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created CSS gradient which represents ruler. The gradient is generated through JS.

### The problem

The ruler generated is OK. The problem starts when user resizes window. You can try this in snippet. It seems, that gradient is heavily cached once rendered, and therefore it has problem with adjusting to changes in parent's width. Some lines of gradient are disappearing, some are changing their width. The problem touches Chrome and Firefox. All solutions I tried were tested only on Fx. I didn't check other browsers.

### Snippet

Snippet starts rendered badly (due to its nature, on website it works as intended), but the resizing window is still the issue.

```css
.ruler {
  height: 20px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(204, 204, 204) 0%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 0.205761%, transparent 0.205761%, transparent 1.99588%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 1.99588%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 2.20165%, transparent 2.20165%, transparent 3.99177%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 3.99177%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 4.19753%, transparent 4.19753%, transparent 5.98765%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 5.98765%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 6.19342%, transparent 6.19342%, transparent 7.98354%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 7.98354%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 8.1893%, transparent 8.1893%, transparent 9.97942%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 9.97942%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 10.1852%, transparent 10.1852%, transparent 11.9753%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 11.9753%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 12.1811%, transparent 12.1811%, transparent 13.9712%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 13.9712%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 14.177%, transparent 14.177%, transparent 15.9671%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 15.9671%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 16.1728%, transparent 16.1728%, transparent 17.963%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 17.963%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 18.1687%, transparent 18.1687%, transparent 19.9588%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 19.9588%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 20.1646%, transparent 20.1646%, transparent 21.9547%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 21.9547%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 22.1605%, transparent 22.1605%, transparent 23.9506%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 23.9506%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 24.1564%, transparent 24.1564%, transparent 25.9465%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 25.9465%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 26.1523%, transparent 26.1523%, transparent 27.9424%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 27.9424%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 28.1481%, transparent 28.1481%, transparent 29.9383%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 29.9383%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 30.144%, transparent 30.144%, transparent 31.9342%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 31.9342%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 32.1399%, transparent 32.1399%, transparent 33.93%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 33.93%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 34.1358%, transparent 34.1358%, transparent 35.9259%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 35.9259%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 36.1317%, transparent 36.1317%, transparent 37.9218%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 37.9218%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 38.1276%, transparent 38.1276%, transparent 39.9177%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 39.9177%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 40.1235%, transparent 40.1235%, transparent 41.9136%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 41.9136%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 42.1193%, transparent 42.1193%, transparent 43.9095%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 43.9095%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 44.1152%, transparent 44.1152%, transparent 45.9053%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 45.9053%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 46.1111%, transparent 46.1111%, transparent 47.9012%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 47.9012%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 48.107%, transparent 48.107%, transparent 49.8971%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 49.8971%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 50.1029%, transparent 50.1029%, transparent 51.893%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 51.893%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 52.0988%, transparent 52.0988%, transparent 53.8889%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 53.8889%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 54.0947%, transparent 54.0947%, transparent 55.8848%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 55.8848%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 56.0905%, transparent 56.0905%, transparent 57.8807%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 57.8807%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 58.0864%, transparent 58.0864%, transparent 59.8765%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 59.8765%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 60.0823%, transparent 60.0823%, transparent 61.8724%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 61.8724%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 62.0782%, transparent 62.0782%, transparent 63.8683%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 63.8683%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 64.0741%, transparent 64.0741%, transparent 65.8642%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 65.8642%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 66.07%, transparent 66.07%, transparent 67.8601%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 67.8601%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 68.0658%, transparent 68.0658%, transparent 69.856%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 69.856%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 70.0617%, transparent 70.0617%, transparent 71.8519%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 71.8519%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 72.0576%, transparent 72.0576%, transparent 73.8477%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 73.8477%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 74.0535%, transparent 74.0535%, transparent 75.8436%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 75.8436%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 76.0494%, transparent 76.0494%, transparent 77.8395%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 77.8395%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 78.0453%, transparent 78.0453%, transparent 79.8354%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 79.8354%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 80.0412%, transparent 80.0412%, transparent 81.8313%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 81.8313%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 82.037%, transparent 82.037%, transparent 83.8272%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 83.8272%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 84.0329%, transparent 84.0329%, transparent 85.823%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 85.823%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 86.0288%, transparent 86.0288%, transparent 87.8189%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 87.8189%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 88.0247%, transparent 88.0247%, transparent 89.8148%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 89.8148%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 90.0206%, transparent 90.0206%, transparent 91.8107%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 91.8107%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 92.0165%, transparent 92.0165%, transparent 93.8066%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 93.8066%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 94.0123%, transparent 94.0123%, transparent 95.8025%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 95.8025%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 96.0082%, transparent 96.0082%, transparent 97.7984%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 97.7984%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 98.0041%, transparent 98.0041%, transparent 99.7942%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 99.7942%, rgb(204, 204, 204))
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="ruler"></div>
</div>
```

### Tried solutions

I've tried almost all I could find on SO solutions, including:

- transform: translateZ
- including new tag inside ruler, and removing it
- adding new  tag to HTML code
- hiding and showing ruler

I've even tried some crazy solutions like changing gradient's parameters:

- angle (changing angle rotates distorted lines, doesn't fix whole thing)
- changing position of colorstops by 0.01%
- drawing everything from right to left

What's even more crazy: even removing the gradient completely, and inserting another, and then copy-pasting removed gradient doesn't refresh the thing.

Only F5 helps.

Is there a way to refresh such a thing?

Comment: As far as I can see, it behaves as expected.  If an element is set to a percentage of the screen width it does change size when you resize the window.

Perhaps you should consider another approach such as using an approach similar to this:
https://codepen.io/j4n/pen/wBVVVN

Comment: It is not working "as expected", because then F5 shouldn't be resetting the lines, if it was expected. Thank You for the link. This one give me one idea how it can be solved another way. The idea of using background-repeat is so dumb stupid I didn't even think of.

Comment: Woops. Sorry, @HenrikClausen. In the link You have provided the exact same error appears during resizing window.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `box-shadow` and `vw` units could do if the idea is to have always the same amont of stripes.

```css
.ruler {
  height:20px;
  border-left:3px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);/* border size will give the width for the shadows */
  width:0;
  box-shadow: 2vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     2vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     4vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     6vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     8vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     10vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     12vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     14vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     16vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     18vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     20vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     22vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     24vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     26vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     28vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     30vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     32vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     34vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     36vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     38vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     40vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     42vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     44vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     46vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     48vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     50vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     52vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     54vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     56vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     58vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     60vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     62vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     64vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     66vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     68vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     70vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     72vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     74vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     76vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     78vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     80vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     82vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     84vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     86vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     88vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     90vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     92vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     94vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     96vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     98vw 0  rgb(204, 204, 204),
     calc(100vw - 3px) 0  rgb(204, 204, 204);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="ruler"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is neat-o idea, but I would need % units, which is impossible with box-shadow (strangely).

Answer (score 0):

For now I've created hard-calculated px values of linear-gradient, and I refresh them during resizing window (throttle set to 50ms). Seems to work good. Code doesn't changed that much (JS it's even simpler), so I won't post it.